# setcookie and get on a other page

Tags: php

How do you get a php cookie on a ohter page than where he is set?

example:

Cookie starts on page: index1.php

```
<?php 
$cookiewaarde = 'example' ;
setcookie("cookiename", $cookiewaarde, time()+ 3600);
?>
```

Cookie will get on page: index2.php

```
<?
if($_COOKIE['cookiename'] != "example") 
{ 
    echo "cookie is set";
}
else 
{ 
    echo 'cookie is not set' ; 
} 
?>
```

But i cant find anny cookie on page index2.php. How can i do this??

Comment: Make sure the 4th param to [setcookie()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) sets a path at the level of or above both scripts which need to access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's the exact code you're using - you're checking to see if the cookie exists with a value of 'mobiel', yet you're actually setting the value as 'example'. On top of that, both cookies have differently spelled names, so won't match anyway.

Answer (score 0):

PHP cannot automatically translate Dutch to English: `'cookienaam' != 'cookiename'`